How get exact value of TimeOfDay?
I want the exact value of TimeOfDay ... My function is
TimeOfDay parseTimeOfDay(String t) {
  DateTime dateTime = DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(t);
  TimeOfDay x = TimeOfDay(hour: dateTime.hour, minute: dateTime.minute);
  return x;
}

the output is showing like this: TimeOfDay(04:45).
But I need the exact vale like this: 04:45.

When you use the returned value, you are calling .toString, instead of .format(context).

String dateTime = DateFormat("HH:mm").format(DateTime.now());
print('current_time=${dateTime}');

